# mobicents jain-slee svn checkout is not working

Tags: eclipse, jboss5.x, restcomm, mobicents, jain-slee

I'm trying to setup Mobicents JAIN SLEE Development Environment using this link[setup](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/MobicentsJAINSLEEDevelopmentEnvironmentSetup?_sscc=t) I followed all the steps but ant the 2nd last step

> svn checkout
>   it throws some error

svn: E160013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://mobicents.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/servers/jain-slee'
svn: E160013: '/svn/trunk/servers/jain-slee' path not found

My question, is it server unavailable or something else

Fyi,
I have installed subversion using, sudo apt-get install subversion.

help and suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You're using outdated documentation. The Documentation for JAIN-SLEE is now available at http://documentation.telestax.com/core/jain_slee/index.html and the source code available at https://github.com/RestComm/jain-slee

Comment: Thank you Jeand, I will follow the documentation and let you know the result. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks please upvote the answer for the benefit of others if happy about the answer.